# Problem Loading Widget

Tags: android, widget

I have a home screen widget. When the user uninstalls the app while the widget is active on the homes screen, the widget is not removed from the home screen and displays a toast-like message box saying "Problem loading widget".

Was that the intended design behaviour? Is there an Intent I can catch that indicates the package is about to be removed?

Related is the behaviour of the CLEAR DATA button. It doesn't just clear the data, it crashes the service behind my widget and when the service restarts, there are no shared preferences for my code to use to resume normal behaviour. Is that the design intention too?

Or were Widgets an after-thought that don't quite fit into the way Android uninstalls applications?